# Having issues with a button in my code that is meant to cycle through many speed multipliers

Tags: processing

I am finishing up a final project for school in which Ive had full creativity on what to make. I decided to make a simple Conway simulator which has  a few buttons on the bottom. One to play/pause, one to step, one to clear and  one to change the speed. It is made in processing and Ive tried implementing the speed button, but whenever I click it it always reverts to 1x speed, even though that was not the expected behaviour. My code is below (processing 3):

```
void setup() {
   size(550, 615);
   pixelDensity(2);
   frameRate(60);
}

//initial array, set as 2 glider guns ----------------------------
boolean[][] colour =  {{false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false, true, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false, true,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false, true,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true, true,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false}
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//game variables -------------------------------------------------
int xposGame = 25;
int yposGame = 25;
int[] arraySize = {50, 50};
int slowDown = 4;
int speedMultiplier = slowDown;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//play button variables ------------------------------------------
int xposPlay = xposGame;
int yposPlay = 550;
int playWidth = 40;
boolean playActive = false;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear button variables -----------------------------------------
int clearWidth = 40;
int xposClear = 485;
int yposClear = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//step button variables ------------------------------------------
int stepWidth = 40;
int xposStep = xposGame + xposPlay + 25;
int yposStep = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//speed multiplier button variables ------------------------------
int speedWidth = 40;
int xposSpeed = xposGame + xposPlay + xposStep;
int yposSpeed = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear the board ------------------------------------------------
void clearArr(){
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      colour[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//iteration function ---------------------------------------------
void iteration(){
  
 //counter for # of neighboring cells
 int neighborNum = 0;
  
 //next generations array
 boolean[][] newColour =  new boolean[arraySize[0]][arraySize[1]];
  
 //read the current generation's array
 for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      
    //search all values around the cell (excluding those outside the array) and count how many neighbors are alive
    if(i != -0){
      if(j != 0){
        if(colour[i-1][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
      if(colour[i-1][j]==true){neighborNum++;}
      if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
        if(colour[i-1][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
    }
      
    if(j != 0){
      if(colour[i][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
    }
    if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
      if(colour[i][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
    }
      
    if(i != arraySize[0]-1){
      if(j != 0){
        if(colour[i+1][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
      if(colour[i+1][j]==true){neighborNum++;}
      if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
        if(colour[i+1][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
    }
        
    //check if the current cell is alive. if it has 2-3 neighbors, it survives, else it doesnt
    if(colour[i][j]==true){
      if(neighborNum==3||neighborNum==2){
        newColour[i][j] = true;
      }
      else{
        newColour[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
        
    //check if the current cell is dead. if it has 3 neighbors, birth it next round
    if(colour[i][j]==false){
      if(neighborNum==3){
        newColour[i][j] = true;
      }
      else{
        newColour[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
       
    //set the number of neighbors on the current cell to 0 for the next cell
    neighborNum = 0;
   }
 }
  
  //set the new array to be the current array
  colour = newColour;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//iteration drawing function -------------------------------------
void drawIteration(){
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      if(colour[i][j] == true){
        fill(255);
      }
      else{fill(0);}
      strokeWeight(2);
      stroke(50);
      rect(10*j+xposGame, 10*i+yposGame, 10, 10);
    }
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//play/pause button function -------------------------------------
void drawPlay(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposPlay, yposPlay, playWidth, playWidth, 5);
  fill(255);
  if(!playActive){
    triangle(xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + playWidth - (playWidth/3.3), xposPlay + (playWidth*3.5/5), yposPlay + (playWidth/2));
  }
  if(playActive){
    rect(xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), playWidth/9, playWidth-(2*(playWidth/3.3)), 2);
    rect(xposPlay + playWidth - (playWidth/3) - (playWidth/9), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), playWidth/9, playWidth-(2*(playWidth/3.3)), 2);
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear button function ------------------------------------------
void drawClear(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposClear, yposClear, clearWidth, clearWidth, 5);
  strokeWeight(clearWidth/9);
  stroke(255);
  line(xposClear+clearWidth/3, yposClear + clearWidth/3, xposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, yposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3);
  line(xposClear+clearWidth/3, yposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, xposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, yposClear + clearWidth/3);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//step button function -------------------------------------------
void drawStep(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposStep, yposStep, stepWidth, stepWidth, 5);
  strokeWeight(stepWidth/9);
  stroke(255);
  line(xposStep + stepWidth/3, yposStep + stepWidth/3, xposStep + (stepWidth*3.5/5), yposStep + (stepWidth/2));
  line(xposStep + stepWidth/3, yposStep + 2*stepWidth/3, xposStep + (stepWidth*3.5/5), yposStep + (stepWidth/2));
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//speed multiplier button ----------------------------------------
void drawSpeed(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposSpeed, yposSpeed, speedWidth, speedWidth, 5);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(25);
  if(slowDown == 12){
    text("1x", xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
  }
  if(slowDown == 6){
    text("2x", xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
  }
  if(slowDown == 4){
    text("3x", xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
  }
  if(slowDown == 3){
    text("4x", xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//all mousePressed events ----------------------------------------
void mousePressed(){
  
  //play button
  if(mouseX > xposPlay && mouseX < xposPlay + playWidth && mouseY > yposPlay && mouseY < yposPlay + playWidth){
    playActive = !playActive;
  }
  
  //clear button
  if(mouseX > xposClear && mouseX < xposClear + clearWidth && mouseY > yposClear && mouseY < yposClear + clearWidth){
    clearArr();
    playActive = false;
  }
  
  //step button
  if(mouseX > xposStep && mouseX < xposStep + stepWidth && mouseY > yposStep && mouseY < yposStep + stepWidth){
    iteration();
    playActive = false;
  }
  
  //speed multiplier button
  if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    if(slowDown == 12){
      slowDown = 6;
    }
    if(slowDown == 6){
      slowDown = 4;
    }
    if(slowDown == 4){
      slowDown = 3;
    }
    if(slowDown == 3){
      slowDown = 2;
    }
    if(slowDown == 2){
      slowDown = 12;
    }
  }
  
  //adding cells
  if(!playActive && mouseX > xposGame && mouseX < xposGame + 10*arraySize[0] && mouseY > yposGame && mouseY < yposGame + 10*arraySize[1]){
      colour[(mouseY-yposGame)/10][(mouseX-xposGame)/10] = !colour[(mouseY-yposGame)/10][(mouseX-xposGame)/10];
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

void draw() {
  background(50);
  noStroke();
  fill(50);
  
  drawPlay();
  drawClear();
  drawStep();
  drawSpeed();
  
  if(speedMultiplier == 0){
    if(playActive){ 
      iteration();
    }
    speedMultiplier = slowDown;
  }
  
  speedMultiplier --;
  
  drawIteration();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your logic looks overly complex and error prone:

```
if(slowDown == 12){
      slowDown = 6;
    }
    if(slowDown == 6){
      slowDown = 4;
    }
    if(slowDown == 4){
      slowDown = 3;
    }
    if(slowDown == 3){
      slowDown = 2;
    }
    if(slowDown == 2){
      slowDown = 12;
    }
```

A basic example is if `slowDown` is `6` you set it `4`, however in the next condition you check if it's `4` and change it to `3` so because it was 6 not only it goes to 4 but immediately after goes to `3`. All your condition trickle down and you end up at `12` in a loop.

Try it out:

```
if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    println("before", slowDown);
    if(slowDown == 12){
      slowDown = 6;
    }
    if(slowDown == 6){
      slowDown = 4;
    }
    if(slowDown == 4){
      slowDown = 3;
    }
    if(slowDown == 3){
      slowDown = 2;
    }
    if(slowDown == 2){
      slowDown = 12;
    }
    println("after", slowDown);
  }
```

The simplest I can think of is to just set `slowDown` to a value:

```
if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    slowDown = 1;
  }
```

If you want multiple speed multipliers maybe you meant to use a [`switch`](https://processing.org/reference/switch.html): ?

```
if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    println("before", slowDown);
    switch(slowDown){
      case 12:
        slowDown = 6;
        break;
      case 6:
        slowDown = 4;
        break;
      case 4:
        slowDown = 3;
        break;
      case 3:
        slowDown = 2;
        break;
      case 2:
        slowDown = 12;
        break;
    }
    println("after", slowDown);
  }
```

In terms of actual behaviour, based on the button labels if looks looks like you want to cycle through speed presets: 1x, 2x, 3x, 4x then back to 1x.

Alternatively you could manage an array of preset options and simply increment (and loop) an index. Optionally you could also use a presets text labels array.

For example:

```
int speedPresetIndex = 0;
int[] speedPresetValues = {12, 6, 4, 3, 2};
String[] speedPresetLabels = {"1x","2x","3x","4x",""};
...
if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    // increment index (looping back to start using %)
    speedPresetIndex = (speedPresetIndex + 1) % speedPresetValues.length; 
    // update slowDown based on preset
    slowDown = speedPresetValues[speedPresetIndex];
  }
...
text(speedPresetLabels[speedPresetIndex], xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
```

Here's modified version of your code with the above changes:

```
void setup() {
   size(550, 615);
   pixelDensity(2);
   frameRate(60);
   println(colour.length, colour[0].length);
}

int speedPresetIndex = 0;
int[] speedPresetValues = {12, 6, 4, 3, 2};
String[] speedPresetLabels = {"1x","2x","3x","4x",""};


//initial array, set as 2 glider guns ----------------------------
boolean[][] colour =  {{false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false, true, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false, true,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false, true,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false, true, true,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true, true,false,false, true,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true,false,false, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false, true, true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                      {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false}
};
//boolean[][] colour = new boolean[50][50];
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//game variables -------------------------------------------------
int xposGame = 25;
int yposGame = 25;
int[] arraySize = {50, 50};
int slowDown = 4;
int speedMultiplier = slowDown;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//play button variables ------------------------------------------
int xposPlay = xposGame;
int yposPlay = 550;
int playWidth = 40;
boolean playActive = false;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear button variables -----------------------------------------
int clearWidth = 40;
int xposClear = 485;
int yposClear = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//step button variables ------------------------------------------
int stepWidth = 40;
int xposStep = xposGame + xposPlay + 25;
int yposStep = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//speed multiplier button variables ------------------------------
int speedWidth = 40;
int xposSpeed = xposGame + xposPlay + xposStep;
int yposSpeed = 550;
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear the board ------------------------------------------------
void clearArr(){
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      colour[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//iteration function ---------------------------------------------
void iteration(){
  
 //counter for # of neighboring cells
 int neighborNum = 0;
  
 //next generations array
 boolean[][] newColour =  new boolean[arraySize[0]][arraySize[1]];
  
 //read the current generation's array
 for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      
    //search all values around the cell (excluding those outside the array) and count how many neighbors are alive
    if(i != -0){
      if(j != 0){
        if(colour[i-1][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
      if(colour[i-1][j]==true){neighborNum++;}
      if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
        if(colour[i-1][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
    }
      
    if(j != 0){
      if(colour[i][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
    }
    if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
      if(colour[i][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
    }
      
    if(i != arraySize[0]-1){
      if(j != 0){
        if(colour[i+1][j-1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
      if(colour[i+1][j]==true){neighborNum++;}
      if(j != arraySize[1]-1){
        if(colour[i+1][j+1]==true){neighborNum++;}
      }
    }
        
    //check if the current cell is alive. if it has 2-3 neighbors, it survives, else it doesnt
    if(colour[i][j]==true){
      if(neighborNum==3||neighborNum==2){
        newColour[i][j] = true;
      }
      else{
        newColour[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
        
    //check if the current cell is dead. if it has 3 neighbors, birth it next round
    if(colour[i][j]==false){
      if(neighborNum==3){
        newColour[i][j] = true;
      }
      else{
        newColour[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
       
    //set the number of neighbors on the current cell to 0 for the next cell
    neighborNum = 0;
   }
 }
  
  //set the new array to be the current array
  colour = newColour;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//iteration drawing function -------------------------------------
void drawIteration(){
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arraySize[1]; j++){
      if(colour[i][j] == true){
        fill(255);
      }
      else{fill(0);}
      strokeWeight(2);
      stroke(50);
      rect(10*j+xposGame, 10*i+yposGame, 10, 10);
    }
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//play/pause button function -------------------------------------
void drawPlay(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposPlay, yposPlay, playWidth, playWidth, 5);
  fill(255);
  if(!playActive){
    triangle(xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + playWidth - (playWidth/3.3), xposPlay + (playWidth*3.5/5), yposPlay + (playWidth/2));
  }
  if(playActive){
    rect(xposPlay + (playWidth/3), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), playWidth/9, playWidth-(2*(playWidth/3.3)), 2);
    rect(xposPlay + playWidth - (playWidth/3) - (playWidth/9), yposPlay + (playWidth/3.3), playWidth/9, playWidth-(2*(playWidth/3.3)), 2);
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//clear button function ------------------------------------------
void drawClear(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposClear, yposClear, clearWidth, clearWidth, 5);
  strokeWeight(clearWidth/9);
  stroke(255);
  line(xposClear+clearWidth/3, yposClear + clearWidth/3, xposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, yposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3);
  line(xposClear+clearWidth/3, yposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, xposClear + 2 * clearWidth/3, yposClear + clearWidth/3);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//step button function -------------------------------------------
void drawStep(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposStep, yposStep, stepWidth, stepWidth, 5);
  strokeWeight(stepWidth/9);
  stroke(255);
  line(xposStep + stepWidth/3, yposStep + stepWidth/3, xposStep + (stepWidth*3.5/5), yposStep + (stepWidth/2));
  line(xposStep + stepWidth/3, yposStep + 2*stepWidth/3, xposStep + (stepWidth*3.5/5), yposStep + (stepWidth/2));
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//speed multiplier button ----------------------------------------
void drawSpeed(){
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  rect(xposSpeed, yposSpeed, speedWidth, speedWidth, 5);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(25);
  text(speedPresetLabels[speedPresetIndex], xposSpeed + (speedWidth/2), yposSpeed + (speedWidth/1.4));
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//all mousePressed events ----------------------------------------
void mousePressed(){
  
  //play button
  if(mouseX > xposPlay && mouseX < xposPlay + playWidth && mouseY > yposPlay && mouseY < yposPlay + playWidth){
    playActive = !playActive;
  }
  
  //clear button
  if(mouseX > xposClear && mouseX < xposClear + clearWidth && mouseY > yposClear && mouseY < yposClear + clearWidth){
    clearArr();
    playActive = false;
  }
  
  //step button
  if(mouseX > xposStep && mouseX < xposStep + stepWidth && mouseY > yposStep && mouseY < yposStep + stepWidth){
    iteration();
    playActive = false;
  }
  
  //speed multiplier button
  if(mouseX > xposSpeed && mouseX < xposSpeed + speedWidth && mouseY > yposSpeed && mouseY < yposSpeed + speedWidth){
    // increment index (looping back to start using %)
    speedPresetIndex = (speedPresetIndex + 1) % speedPresetValues.length; 
    // update slowDown based on preset
    slowDown = speedPresetValues[speedPresetIndex];
  }
  
  //adding cells
  if(!playActive && mouseX > xposGame && mouseX < xposGame + 10*arraySize[0] && mouseY > yposGame && mouseY < yposGame + 10*arraySize[1]){
      colour[(mouseY-yposGame)/10][(mouseX-xposGame)/10] = !colour[(mouseY-yposGame)/10][(mouseX-xposGame)/10];
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

void draw() {
  background(50);
  noStroke();
  fill(50);
  
  drawPlay();
  drawClear();
  drawStep();
  drawSpeed();
  
  if(speedMultiplier == 0){
    if(playActive){ 
      iteration();
    }
    speedMultiplier = slowDown;
  }
  
  speedMultiplier --;
  
  drawIteration();
}
```

Hopefully this solves your main question.

Additionally I have a few suggestions that could be helpful:

- [avoid repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in code. all mouse / button rectangle boundary checks could be encapsulate the logic in a reusable function. (If class at school went over classes you could implement and reuse a Button class). You can see example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042779/how-to-add-a-play-again-button/68042887#68042887). Even though it's in p5.js the syntax is very similar.
- again, if classes were taught, the 2D CA could be encapsulated into a re-usable class
- this is more of a nice to have suggestion: instead of the large 2D boolean array being manually defined like that, you could potentially use a .png image where `true` is marked as white pixels on a black background. With this approach a future version could potentially not only draw but also save / load 2D CA configurations.

The rest is not bad at all (fairly clean code, consistent naming, etc.) ! Nice work!

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! Regarding the first suggestion, yes we did get into classes, but I didn't understand it fully, especially in regard to objects. We also got into classes after the majority of the code was written, so I didn't bother to change it. I will absolutely try to understand further! 

And the last suggestion, I was highly considering adding preloaded boards, but I had absolutely no clue how to. My original Idea was to use a text file but I didn't look into it enough and I was running out of time. 

Thank you for all the suggestions!

Comment: If the answer was helpful please vote it up and if it was the solution to your problem also mark it with the green check mark. I get this is a school project and it's good you're focusing on what matters to deliver on time. Indeed it would be good to revisit the code and as practice use classes as well. I like the text file idea more than the .png idea ! If you copy the `colour` values into a plain text file with .json extension and find/replace all { with [ and } with ] you could load that into Processing via [`loadJSONArray()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONArray_.html)...

Comment: ...or alternatively `true` , `false` could change to `1`,`0` and with a bit of formatting you could end up with a .csv table you could read in Processing via [`loadTable()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadTable_.html). After your deadlines, if you're still curious you could post a separate question about this: I'd be more than happy to answer and I'm sure others might also contribute too.